# python cmake chooses wrong Windows SDK version

Tags: python, c++, cmake, sdk

I try to compile the [Frechet-CUDA](https://github.com/StefanMeintrup/Frechet-CUDA) package for python. I installed C++ via Visual Studio and installed dlib and cmake for python to compile the package. Still get the following error:

```
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22000.0 to target Windows 10.0.19043.
CMake Error at C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR system chrono
  program_options python3 numpy3) (Required is at least version "1.63") 
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2376 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:23 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Anwender/Documents/GitHub/Artjom_bachelor_thesis/py/build/temp.win-amd64-cpython-37/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".     
See also "C:/Users/Anwender/Documents/GitHub/Artjom_bachelor_thesis/py/build/temp.win-amd64-cpython-37/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 81, in <module>
    zip_safe=False,
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\__init__.py", line 87, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
    return run_commands(dist)
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 973, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 992, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\command\install.py", line 74, in run
    self.do_egg_install()
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\command\install.py", line 123, in do_egg_install
    self.run_command('bdist_egg')
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 992, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 165, in run
    cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 151, in call_command
    self.run_command(cmdname)
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 992, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\command\install_lib.py", line 11, in run
    self.build()
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\_distutils\command\install_lib.py", line 112, in build
    self.run_command('build_ext')
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 992, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "setup.py", line 35, in run
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "setup.py", line 64, in build_extension
    cwd=self.build_temp, env=env)
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 328, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\Anwender\\Documents\\GitHub\\Artjom_bachelor_thesis\\py/..', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\Anwender\\Documents\\GitHub\\Artjom_bachelor_thesis\\py\\build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\Anwender\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\Anwender\\Documents\\GitHub\\Artjom_bachelor_thesis\\py\\build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

My best guess is that `CMake` is unable to choose the correct SDK version. I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34631913/how-to-set-the-default-windows-kit-sdk-version) to enforce a specific SDK version which I certainly installed on my device. Sadly the file mentioned in the solution does not contain the paragraph for a default SDK version. I tried to insert the mentioned paragraph but the process still fails with the exact same error.

Feel free to ask for more information about programme versions or my device!

My sys spec is the following:

System : Win 10

Python-ver: 3.7

Latest SDK version:

Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.1_1004.584.2120.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.1_1004.584.2120.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe

EDIT I : The `CMakeOutput.log` file contains only the following line :

The system is: Windows - 10.0.19043 - AMD64

EDIT II : I have Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-Bit) - Current
Version 17.3.3 installed on my machine.
My C++ version :
Visual C++ 2022   00482-90000-00000-AA994

EDIT III : This is not a CUDA problem. The CUDA toolset is not needed to install the package.

EDIT IV : I've updated the SDK version as mentioned by @Tsyvarev. Still the compilation error persists.

Comment: CMake configures the project for Visual Studio and msbuild which corresponds to it. So, which Visual Studio you have installed on your machine? (Note, that Visual Studio is NOT a VS Code).

Comment: I have Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-Bit) - Current
Version 17.3.3 installed on my machine.

Comment: @Tsyvarev is there any information, that I have missed, which would help to solve this question?

Comment: You need either to configure your Visual Studio to use proper default SDK, or you need to tell CMake to configure your project with proper SDK. I am not an expert with Visual Studio and don't know the way it is configured. If you want to tell CMake about your SDK version, then you could set `CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION` variable, either in the command line or in the `CMakeLists.txt`, like suggested in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63612743/how-to-pass-latest-windows-sdk-version-to-cmake).

Comment: Done! Still the error persists! Any further recommendations? I updated the stacktrace aswell.

Comment: "Still the error persists!" - Well, you actually got **other** error, and it is not about SDK version, as the current title states.

Comment: As for debugging Boost problems, you could try to set `Boost_DEBUG` option as described in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html) and check output it produces. The option could be set either in the command line (`-DBoost_DEBUG=ON`) or in the `CMakeLists.txt` (`set (Boost_DEBUG ON)`).

Comment: You are perfectly right here. Sry for that misleading comment. Since this question dives into a completly new direction I will close this one and open another.